# How to verify the accounts have specifc access rights on the file shares using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I need to verify the below file shares exist and the accounts have the specific access rights as below.

File shares - ADMIN$, Abc_Projects2$, Xyz_Projects$

SYSTEM and Administrators must have full access,
Users must have read access, Thank you

For Example:

```
Name   ScopeName AccountName              AccessControlType AccessRight
----   --------- -----------              ----------------- -----------
ADMIN$ *         BUILTIN\Administrators   Allow             Full
ADMIN$ *         SYSTEM                   Allow             Full
ADMIN$ *         Users                    Allow             Read
```

I have written the below code to verify if a share exists

```
$fileShares = @("ADMIN$", "Abc_Projects2$", "Xyz_Projects$")

function VerifyFileShares {
  param (
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]$fileShares
  )

  ForEach ($fileShare in $fileShares) {
    If (Get-SMBShare | Where-Object NAME -EQ $fileShare) {
      "$fileShare is mapped"
    } 
    else {
      "$fileShare is not mapped"
    }
  }
}

VerifyFileShares -fileShares $fileShares
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [NTFS module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85) it would be very easy to verify permissions.  A quick example:

```
Get-NTFSAccess -Path <PathToShare> -Account <UserOrGroup>
```

This would output something like:

```
Account                             Access Rights   Applies to                Type    IsInherited   InheritedFrom
-------                             -------------   ----------                ----    -----------   -------------
BUILTIN\Administrators              FullControl     ThisFolderSubfoldersAn... Allow   True          c:
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                 FullControl     ThisFolderSubfoldersAn... Allow   True          c:
```

Of course it would take a little work to nest in your file share checks etc...  However, there are many options.